# Retrieving data from Firebase but not showing

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-retrieval

This is my firebase database from where I want to retrieve all the names of universities in `ListView` click here to see image

[image: This is my firebase database from where I want to retrieve all the names of universities in <code>ListView</code> click here to see image]

```
   myRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
   myRef.child("Universities").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                database c = postSnapshot.getValue(database.class);
                final String name = c.getuniName();
                userNameList.add(name);

                final ArrayAdapter<String> mutahirAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , userNameList);
                mListView.setAdapter(mutahirAdapter);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

**Database Class**
*I added data directly in Firebase now I am not getting the data in the `ListView` i wanted to retrieve all the child's of universities in `ListView`*

```
package com.mutahir.futureguide;

public class database {
    String Name;
    public String uniName(String Name) {
        this.Name= Name;
        return Name;
    }

    public String getuniName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setuniName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Dear @SushinPv data is not showing in the listview

Comment: program crashes when it is going in the main activity

Comment: Please paste a snapshot of your firebase datasets

Comment: If the app is crashing then please paste the error log here

Comment: i already Uploaded  click the first link

Comment: at com.mutahir.futureguide.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:67)
showing error in 67 line means 
database c = postSnapshot.getValue(database.class);
showing error in this line

Comment: Ok wait I'll update the answer

Comment: okay Thanks 
JUST wants to get all the universities name in the list view 
thats all i want

Comment: Check the below answer

Comment: @Mutahir Based on your code and comments It looks like that the problem is with your model class. You get a `map<String,Object>` and you want to parse  it as a `database` which is not a `map<String,Object>`.

Comment: @BirendraSingh yeah i think the same thing because i dont have better concept of database class that is why i posted first time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope it worked!

```
myRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
myRef.child("Universities").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            final String name = postSnapshot.getValue("name").toString();
            userNameList.add(name);
        }
        if(!userNameList.isEmpty()){
            final ArrayAdapter<String> mutahirAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , userNameList);
            mListView.setAdapter(mutahirAdapter);
       }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```